# How layout_weight works?

Tags: java, android, view, graphics

I researched on another stackoverflow question//answer and found a working definition of layout_weight to be that  "This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view, and allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view"
(source:[What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean))

I am trying to apply that concept to my code.
Currently my code (without the layout weights) is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Home"
       android:gravity="center"
     />
    <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="About"
       android:gravity="center"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the current layout is https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTPGg.jpg
(the home should take up all the space bc of match_parent)

However if i add android:layout_weight="1" to both text views,
i get this layout  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y1Na.jpg

(Both are visible and share same amount of space)

My question is how is this happening from that working definition of layout_weight? layout_weight in this example will assign extra space equally to both the text views. But there is no extra space because the first one has width match_parent which will make it take the width of the entire parent(no extra space)

Comment: The system calculates the `weight_sum` since you didn't give it one. This comes to 2 so it then divvies up the `width` accordingly which comes to half for both. What exactly are you trying to do (what do you want it to be)? To use `weight` correctly, your width should be "0dp" in a horizontally oriented `LinearLayout`

Comment: it produces the right result but i thought layout_weight just had to do with dividing up extra space and in this case, there was no extra space

Comment: No, that is incorrect. If the previous views don't use weight then you can use it to give others the remaining space. But giving a weight to each view makes them act accordingly. So, it you had weight of .3 on one and .6 on the other then the latter would take up approx. 2/3

Comment: thx that makes more sense

Comment: Adding on to that. If you had 3 views(with no extra space) and two of them had weights of 1 assigned to them and one did not specify weight. How would that work in terms of what you just stated?

Comment: What would the width be of the third view? Anyway, you would have to play with it. I'm not an expert on the subject and it depends on various properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is this happening ?

To fix the ideas, let's say that LinearLayout's width is 100px.

- TextView Home is MATCH_PARENT so 100px
- TextView About is MATCH_PARENT so 100px

So, total width used by children is 100px+100px = 200px

Now, let's compute the remaining width : this is the difference between the available width and the width used by all children :

`RemainingWidth = AvailableWidth (100px) - TotalWidthUsedByChildren (200px) = -100px`

**Note that it is negative**

There is 2 child views, so distribute the remaining width to each of them according their weight. In this case each child receive 50% of the remaining... it means that each child receive -50px.

So finally :

- TextView Home width is 100px + -50px = 50px
- TextView About width is 100px + -50px = 50px

Perfectly logic, but not very intuitive. So the recommendation when using layout_weight is to always set the width of chid views to 0.